How to apply a specific layout inside a root layout?
I would like to apply a specific layout to a page inside a parent folder which has its own root layout.
I have this folder structure:
src
  app
    (routes)
      admin
        users
        payments
        settings
        example
          [id]
            page.tsx
            layout.tsx
        layout.tsx
        page.tsx
    api
    components
    page.tsx
    layout.tsx

Here I would like to apply a different layout to /admin/example/:id and even I put layout.tsx (example/[id]/layout.tsx), it is still getting admin's layout (admin/layout.tsx) too.
I also looked at route grouping stuff but not really understood why I need to delete my root layout (src/app/layout.tsx) where I put all my general providers such as clerk, upload services, etc.

Given your file tree, your route /admin/example/:id, which is inside the folder src/app/(routes)/admin/example/[id] has the following layouts associated to it in the following order:

src/app/layout.tsx - your root layout.
src/app/(routes)/admin/layout.tsx - the admin layout.
src/app/(routes)/admin/example/[id]/layout.tsx - the layout for /admin/example/:id.

You have to keep in mind that for a given page.tsx file, the layouts applied are the ones located in any of the parent directories, this is the reason why your /admin/example/:id route renders the admin layout because it is in one of the parent directories of your page file.

Route grouping actually helps you here to avoid having a layout.tsx file that you do not want in the parent directories of your page.tsx.
In this case, your solution would be to re-organize your route tree in such a way that the route /admin/example/:id's page.tsx file does not have the admin's layout.tsx in any of the parent directories.
For example:
src
  app
    (routes)
      admin
        users
        payments
        settings
        layout.tsx
        page.tsx
      (otherAdmin)
        admin
          example
            [id]
              page.tsx
              layout.tsx
    api
    components
    page.tsx
    layout.tsx

By moving the folder src/app/(routes)/admin/example/[id] to src/app/(routes)/(otherAdmin)/admin/example/[id], it will no longer be child of any the admin folder with its layout.tsx file, meaning that in this case, the relevant layouts for this file would be:

src/app/layout.tsx - your root layout.
src/app/(routes)/(otherAdmin)/admin/example/[id]/layout.tsx - the layout for /admin/example/:id.


I really wanted to access the example at /admin/example/:id. But if there is no way around, then I may have to use your suggested file tree.

By using the example provided, your route will still be available at /admin/example/:id, notice that inside the (otherAdmin) group there is another admin folder. Route groups (the ones wrapped in parentheses) do not affect the path of the route.

Interesting, thanks. Is there any side effect of using this file structure?

There's no side effects. It all just comes down to your needs. Personally I think it does add some sort abstraction to keep in mind because the rest of the admin routes are in separate group and use a different layout, but other than that it does not compromise anything.
